# Enlarging Control

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

Hi I am currently building a flash card productivity app which has has a user control that i have made. On making the control i realized that it was too small for to be displayed well or rendered well on my phones display. So i then began to enlarge the user control by increasing the width and height of the control and also increasing the size of the text of all the controls contained in the user control .Only when i one try to run the control i get given this exception : 
An exception of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in SuperCards.exe but was not handled in user code

WinRT information: Failed to create a '%1' from the text '%0'. [Line: 12 Position: 48]

Additional information: The text associated with this error code could not be found.

Here is the xaml code for the user control :

```
<UserControl
x:Class="SuperCards.CardPackItemListView"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:SuperCards"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="125"
d:DesignWidth="400" >
    <Border CornerRadius="2" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="White">
        <Grid Background="White" Height="Auto" Width=" Auto">
            <TextBlock x:Name="cardPackItemNameDisplay" HorizontalAlignment="Left"      VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Text="(Sample) Periodic Table" Foreground="Gray" Margin="9,9,0,0" FontSize="30" />
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="9,30,9,9" Width="Auto" Height="9" Background="gray" >
                 <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="Red" Width="46"/> 
            </Grid>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="36" Foreground="Gray" Margin="0,9,9,0" FontSize="30"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
```

and here visual studios notified that the exception was not handled at the initializing component inside the constructor of the user control.

Comment: What's your `xmlns:local="using:SuperCards"` doing?

Comment: I don't know isn't that just added by default ?

Comment: Yea sorry I'm just used to seeing more like ="clr-namespace:viewmodel" but what I'm specifically looking for is if there was something requiring a type converter or something because as it shows currently, not sure what the hell ya got going on as your culprit for that error. Might have to show some code.

Comment: `using:` is a WinRT convention; the question was incorrectly tagged as relating to WPF.

Comment: That pretty much all there is i create a new instance of the user control and add it to a stack panel but for some reason i keep get this exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following attribute on line 12 corresponds with the line in the error message; remove the leading space within the quotes:

```
Width=" Auto"
```

This may also cause problems if color names in WinRT are case sensitive; best to capitalize the `G` in `Gray` just in case:

```
Background="gray"
```

Comment: Thanks that did the trick. Could you please explain why it wasn't working before

Comment: `WidthConverter` expects a valid `double` value or `"Auto"`, but you specified `" Auto"`, which doesn't match exactly, and so it failed to convert your `Width` value.  The error message looks like it wasn't populated properly; the `%0` and `%1` look like placeholders for the property type and the specified value.  It probably should have read `Failed to create a 'double' [or perhaps 'Width'] from the text ' Auto'.`, which would have been far more useful.

Comment: damnit @MikeStrobel I didn't even notice the space. Got to quit speeding through these lol, +1